# SQL Query, LEFT JOINs with NULLs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am trying to create a list of hours by Company and Date, even if the Company does not have data for that Date. I've tried LEFT JOINing a Calendar table and Grouping on its dates and then Company, but to no avail.

```
SELECT cal.date, comp.name, comp.hours
FROM company AS comp
LEFT JOIN calendar AS cal ON cal.date=comp.date
GROUP BY cal.date, comp.name
```

I expect to get NULL outputs when a Company does not have hours for that Date, like so:

```
2018-01-01   Company A   100
2018-01-01   Company B   NULL
2018-01-02   Company A   NULL
2018-01-02   Company B   NULL
2018-01-03   Company A   100
2018-01-03   Company B   50
```

But it only returns rows where data can be found, as if I used an INNER JOIN. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Here is a MCVE, so that your question does not get closed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/517b4e/4/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made 3 mistakes, of which 2 are relevant:

1. You swapped the order of the tables in the join (easy to fix)
2. Your query does not reflect your stated intent (harder to fix)
3. You are using `GROUP BY` when it is unnecessary (irrelevant in this particular case)

I'll focus on 2. You're close to your goal but not all there. Fixing the first and third mistakes, here is your query:

```
SELECT cal.date, comp.name, comp.hours
FROM calendar AS cal
LEFT JOIN company AS comp ON cal.date=comp.date
```

This is going to do something like the following:

```
For each cal_row in calendar:
    For each comp_row in company:
        If cal_row.date equals comp_row.date:
            Create output row and append to output
    If no rows created:
        Create output row, fill with NULLs, and append to output
```

So your query guarantees at least 1 output row per date. What you are looking for is 1 output row *per date, per company*. One way to do this is by creating an intermediate table, and left-joining to that:

```
SELECT tbl.date, tbl.name, comp.hours
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cal.date, comp.name
    FROM calendar AS cal
    CROSS JOIN company as comp
) AS tbl
LEFT JOIN LEFT JOIN company AS comp ON
    tbl.date = comp.date AND tbl.name= comp.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/517b4e/11/0

This matches your desired output.

Comment: Also they are misusing GROUP BY (which, granted, they don't need) because non-aggregated SELECTed columns are not all functionally dependent on the grouping columns.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for helping me understand the problems in my logic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use calendar as a left table,in that case you will get all the date

```
SELECT cal.date, comp.name, comp.hours
FROM calendar  AS cal  
LEFT JOIN company AS comp ON cal.date=comp.date
```

I have not found any aggregate function so i removed group by

Comment: This does not produce the desired output shown in the question

Comment: @shadowtalker yes i know but i described it will show all the date where null op finds